# pdf generated upside down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf-generation, cgcontextdrawimage

I am creating pdf using below code

```
UIImage *CurImage=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[ImageArr objectAtIndex:i]];
UIView *ViewDraw=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10, pageSize, pageSize)];  
ViewDraw.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
CGContextBeginPage (pdfContext,nil);

//turn PDF upsidedown
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,CurImage.size.height);
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextConcatCTM(pdfContext, transform);
int y = (pageSize - CurImage.size.height)/2;
int x = (pageSize - CurImage.size.width)/2;

[CurImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( (ViewDraw.frame.width - curImage.frame.width)/2, 24, size.width, curImage.frame.height)];

//        CGContextDrawImage(pdfContext, CGRectMake(x,-y, CurImage.size.width, CurImage.size.height), CurImage.CGImage);
CGContextEndPage (pdfContext);
CurImage=nil;
```

but it is generating upside down i.e.180 degree with mirror image.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn PDF upside-down:

```
CGAffineTransform aCgAffTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,892); //here the whole PDF page height should be given 
aCgAffTrans = CGAffineTransformScale(aCgAffTrans, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextConcatCTM(aCgPDFContextRef, aCgAffTrans);
```

Your are providing some random height while some part gets turned down and others remains the same. So a mirror like effect appears.

Comment: Your original identify transform gets immediately thrown away—you can make this clearer by just assigning the result of CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation directly in the declaration of aCgAffTrans.